# Webpack build fail when adding a specific external lib

Tags: node.js, webpack

It happens on a build for server side, i am already using a lot of external modules and everything worked great until now.

I am trying to add the module `auth0-js` and the error happens when i add the import on this lib `var crypto = require('crypto'); TypeError: require is not a function`.

Here is my webpack config (for server side):

```
const path = require('path');

const webpack = require('webpack');
const StatsPlugin = require('stats-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './handler.js',
  target: 'node',

  profile: false,

  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist-server'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'handler.js',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs'
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, '..'),
        use: 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.pug$/,
        use: 'pug-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      __CLIENT__: false,
      __SERVER__: true
    }),
    new StatsPlugin('stats.json', {
      chunkModules: true,
      exclude: [/node_modules[\\\/]react/]
    })
  ],
  resolve: {
    modules: [
      path.resolve('./src'),
      path.resolve('./node_modules')
    ]
  },
  devtool: 'source-map'
};
```

My .babelrc file is:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "react",
    "latest"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-object-rest-spread",
    "transform-runtime"
  ]
}
```

I tried to remove the exclude node_modules but i get other errors.

I am curious to know how a single library can break everything, what should i do?

Comment: Could you share your tsconfig.json ?

Comment: Could you also share the code block where you are specifying the 'require'? It could be simply due to an error on the previous line causing  a parse issue? Also, which version of nodejs?

Comment: @JoséQuintoZamora i am not using typescript this is a ReactJS code.

Comment: @AndreM it is just a single line ``import auth0 from 'auth0-js';`` this is not a require i am doing myself but a require executing by the module, maybe webpack only wants to parse imports and not require ?

Comment: Could you try adding the `es2015` preset (make it the first one) and see if it helps?

Comment: @AndreM the latest preset wrap es2015, es2016 and es2017, so i tried es2015 just for the test and it doesn't change anything.